# Lid stays for shallow box

Tags: wood

I have a window seat with shallow storage underneath (100mm deep storage, 560mm deep lid of 18mm birch ply). I've not had any luck finding soft close lid stays. The piston ones I've tried are soft close until 45 degrees and then they slam shut because I can't put the piston deep enough to get a relatively decent angle. The hinged stays (hafele duo flap) require about 180mm of clearance so I can't use those.

Due to the weight of the lid (5-6kg), I can't rely on soft close hinges. Poorly sketched diagram below:

Anything else I can try to keep small fingers safe?!

[image]

Comment: This is likely to be off-topic, but a diagram of what you're trying to achieve might help.

Comment: Added an image link

Comment: perhaps you need to use gas springs that are attached to the lid at one end and to a sliding block at the other end .... the sliding block hits the back of the box before the lid is fully closed and the springs cushion the lid closing

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking for **soft close cabinet hinges**. Unless I misunderstand your situation, what you have is equivalent to a cabinet on its back. These are commonly available at most home improvement stores. There are also retrofit kits that are basically a tiny piston that'll slow down the very last bit of closing, which is the important bit.

Comment: It's basically that, but the lid is very heavy so soft close hinges can't support the weight as it closes

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post an "ad" for a specific product, and normally I wouldn't, but [Rockler](https://www.rockler.com/lid-stay-torsion-hinge-lid-support-rustic-bronze) makes a torsion hinge which, in my experience seems to be somewhat unique and might work for you in this application. I've used several sets of these on various toy boxes, etc. and they seem to work pretty much like laptop computer hinges. They're easy to open and close but the lid (or whatever) will stay where you leave it.

Also, [Sugastune](https://www.sugatsune.com/shop/?s=dampering%20hinges&fwp_per_page=12) makes dampening hinges that might work too, but I've never used these in building anything. I bought a set and put them on the shelf in the shop, then found the Rockler hinges above. They seem to be well made and good quality, etc.